# What kind of worm/bug is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, pest-control

Recently, I found a few worms in my bathroom and I am wondering what kind of worms are they. They move slowly and they are about 6-9 millimetres long. It seems that they are not sensitive to water. Are they harmful parasites or harmless creatures? For your information, I live in Turkey.

Here are photos of a selected worm.

[image: worm1]

[image: worm2]

[image: worm3]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this creature. The location can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles (e.g. from the side and below) could also be helpful. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: This is almost certainly a fly larvae of some kind. My initial guess was [Psychodidae](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/URBAN/FLIES/drain_fly.html) due to the bathroom location and siphon-like structure, but the body shape (wide and tapering vs long and narrow) and lack of distinct head leave me guessing this is *not* correct.

Comment: Possibly ***Fannia***? (See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Third-instars-of-necrophagous-flies-a-Calliphoridae-Calliphora-vomitoria-b_fig1_226946269), [here](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2011/11/29/larvae-or-seeds-or-larvae-and-seeds/), [here](https://www.insecte.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=135898), and [here](http://www.parlonsbonsai.com/forums/index.php/topic/49314-identification/)). Can you provide any additional (BETTER QUALITY) photos or more context (where in the bathroom? do you have cigarettes in the bathroom?, any dead bodies?, anything else to note?)?

Comment: These worms were crawling on the floor. Also there was an almost full trash can in my bathroom and were no cigarettes. ResearchGate reference photos resembles these worms and your explanation of a fly larvae of some kind is pretty convincing. Because I don't own a pet or any other animal at my home. Maybe they went out from the trash can to the floor. I cannot provide better photos since I cleaned all my bathroom and fortunately there are no signs of them anymore. If you provide your answer below, I can accept it.